# Socicon font not displaying with @font-face

Tags: html, css, fonts, icons, font-face

I want to use a font named socicon (http://socicon.com/) in my header, instead of having .png of social icons. Thus I can style my icons more easily and quickly.

So I followed the instructions given on the socicon website, and here is a sample of my code

// HTML

```
<section class="social">
                <ul>
                    <li><div class="container"><a href="https://twitter.com/xxx" target="_blank" class="icon" id="twitter">a</a></div></li>
                    <li><div class="container"><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/pub/xxx" target="_blank" class="icon" id="linkedin">j</a></div></li>
                    <li><div class="container"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/xxx" target="_blank" class="icon" id="facebook">b</a></div></li>
                </ul>
            </section>
```

// CSS

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'socicon';
src: url('fonts/socicon-webfont.eot');
src: url('fonts/socicon-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('fonts/socicon-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('fonts/socicon-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('fonts/socicon-webfont.svg#sociconregular') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}

.icon {
color: #ffffff;
font-family: 'socicon' !important;
font-size: 28px;
text-decoration: none;
position: absolute;
top: 1%;
padding-left: 17px;
padding-right: 17px;
padding-top: 30px;
padding-bottom: 60px;
transition: all .4s linear;
-webkit-transition: all .4s linear;
-moz-transition: all .4s linear;
-o-transition: all .4s linear;
-ms-transition: all .4s linear;
}
```

But instead of the wanted icon, the letters a, j, b keep appearing. I tried installing the font in my OS, and then the icons are displayed, but as soon as the font is not on the system, the @font-face call does not seem to work.

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 1):

`src` must include `../fonts/` and not only `fonts/`. The latter works for html but not for css apparently.

Answer (score 0):

> [...]as soon as the font is not on the system, the @font-face call does
>   not seem to work.

If you look at the `@font-face` rule you will see that the `src` is set to a relative path (e.g. `fonts/socicon-webfont.eot`), therefore, if the font is at this location, the font will not resolve, thus, if the font has not been placed on your system/at this location then it will not load as anticipated.

```
src: url('fonts/socicon-webfont.eot'); /* Local location of font */
src: url('fonts/socicon-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* Local location of font */
     url('fonts/socicon-webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Local location of font */
     url('fonts/socicon-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), /* Local location of font */
     url('fonts/socicon-webfont.svg#sociconregular') format('svg'); /* Local location of font */
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the font will not resolve", but anyway the 4 font files are placed in the fonts folder, same as specified in the `src`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your own path, where Socicon is stored on your server.
Maybe you put Socicon font in a folder called stuff. And that your css are in a folder of their own. Then you would have to write : ../stuff/socicon-webfont.eot
Or use an absolute path : http://www.yoursite/stuff/socicon-webfont.eot

Regards,

Quentin